# Why do I have memory leak for the following code with channel sub/unsub?

Tags: clojure, core.async

I am using `[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"],[org.clojure/core.async "1.2.603"]` and the latest Amazon Corretto 11 JVM if there was anything to do with them.

The following code is a simplified version of the code used in production and it does cause memory leak. I have no idea why that happened but suspect it might due to sub/unsub of channels. Can anyone help point out where my code may go wrong or how I can fix the memory leak?

```clj
(ns test-gc.core
  (:require [clojure.core.async :as a :refer [chan put! close! <! go >! go-loop timeout]])
  (:import [java.util UUID]))

(def global-msg-ch (chan (a/sliding-buffer 200)))

(def global-msg-pub (a/pub global-msg-ch :id))

(defn io-promise []
  (let [id (UUID/randomUUID)
        ch (chan)]
    (a/sub global-msg-pub id ch)
    [id (go
          (let [x (<! ch)]
            (a/unsub global-msg-pub id ch)
            (:data x)))]))

(defn -main []
  (go-loop []
    (<! (timeout 1))
    (let [[pid pch] (io-promise)
          cmd {:id   pid
               :data (rand-int 1E5)}]
      (>! global-msg-ch cmd)
      (println (<! pch)))
    (recur))
  (while true
    (Thread/yield)))
```

A quick heap dump gives the following statistics for example:

- Class by number of instances

  - `java.util.LinkedList`                        5,157,128 (14.4%)
  - `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference` 3,698,382 (10.3%)
  - `clojure.lang.Atom`                           3,094,279 (8.6%)
  - ...
- Class by size of instances

  - `java.lang.Object[]`    210,061,752 B (13.8%)
  - `java.util.LinkedList`  206,285,120 B (13.6%)
  - `clojure.lang.Atom`     148,525,392 B (9.8%)
  - `clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel` 132,022,336 B (8.7%)
  - ...

Comment: What is the goal of this code?

Comment: @AlanThompson I would admit this is a bad code/design. But the primary goal was to handle to async response of API calling. The request of a client is distributed to several modules and when all done, a finishing message with extra data is then send to the `global-msg-ch` and then retrieved for each request (as you may guess, each request is labeled by `UUID`).

Comment: What kind of memory leak do you have? Could you paste the Out of Memory Exception?

Comment: @rcastellcastell It just says `Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "async-dispatch-1"` alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out why. By looking at the source code, we get the following segment:

```clj
(defn pub
  "Creates and returns a pub(lication) of the supplied channel, ..."
  ...
     (let [mults (atom {}) ;;topic->mult
           ensure-mult (fn [topic]
                         (or (get @mults topic)
                             (get (swap! mults
                                         #(if (% topic) % (assoc % topic (mult (chan (buf-fn topic))))))
                                  topic)))
           p (reify
              Mux
              (muxch* [_] ch)

              Pub
              (sub* [p topic ch close?]
                    (let [m (ensure-mult topic)]
                      (tap m ch close?)))
              (unsub* [p topic ch]
                      (when-let [m (get @mults topic)]
                        (untap m ch)))
              (unsub-all* [_] (reset! mults {}))
              (unsub-all* [_ topic] (swap! mults dissoc topic)))]
       ...
       p)))
```

We can see `mults` stores all `topic` hence shall increase monotonically if we do not clear it.  We may add something like `(a/unsub-all* global-msg-pub pid)` to fix that.